# Is 'tête-à-tête' an expression in English language as well?

Tags: loanwords

tête-à-tête is a French expression; however, I see it on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/tete-a-tete). What confused me most was that it is not 'tete-a-tete' but 'tête-à-tête' in the dictionary.

Comment: The *Cambridge Dictionary* keeps accents on foreign expressions, even ones as common as *fiancé*. Most native English speakers don't.

Comment: @PeterShor That's what I was wondering, thanks!

Comment: English writers don't generally use accents, and if they do it's frequently wrong, or at least random. English readers normally ignore accents on printed words, and so do newspapers and other printed material, which each have their own particular "proper" ways of doing it, most of which are also random.

Comment: In American English, it's pronounced /tɛɾə'tɛt/, with the last, stressed syllable aspirated [tʰɛt].

Comment: @JohnLawler Great information, thanks!

Comment: Even in French the marks don't express pronunciation and are just there for decoration.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte) documents that we also use it as an adjective for *private*; the Cambridge entry does not.

Comment: @DjinTonic: I don't believe it can be used as a generic adjective for private; just in contexts where there is a private conversation involved.

Comment: @PeterShor Correct, although M-W doesn't make that clear. ["*Did you understand that it was to be a tête-à-tête dinner ?*"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mordaunt_Divorce_Case/_qjiQEVIA7wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: The OED has a L. M. Alcott citation: "Such a cunning teakettle and saucepan, and a tête-à-tête set."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression has been used in English for a long time.

[tete-a-tete](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tete-a-tete) (n.):

> "a private meeting," from French tête-à-tête, literally "head-to-head," from Old French teste "head" (see tete). The adjective, "private, confidential, with none present but the persons concerned" is recorded from 1728; as an adverb from 1790.

(Etymonline)

According to the [Grammarist:](https://grammarist.com/usage/tete-a-tete/)

> The phrase sometimes appears in English texts with the French accent marks. English speakers are not kind to these marks, though, and the anglicized, unaccented form is much more common.

Curiously, the original French version appears to have become more common in recent years according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tete-a-tete%2C%20t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctete%20-%20a%20-%20tete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%AAte%20-%20%C3%A0%20-%20t%C3%AAte%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: +1 for "English speakers are not kind to these marks."